# TableView Header initialized from nib doesn't fit TableView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uikit

I'm instantiating a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass and an `UITableViewCell` subclass for my `UITableView` from nib files.

You can't use the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` in the IB, so I've avoided the problem by adding an `UITableViewCell` to the nib file subclassed as `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, which gives it a content view and allows it to function normally.

The problem is:

Cells' width is resized to fit the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` stays exactly the same as in the nib file. When you rotate the device, or use a device with bigger screen width, it still stays the same as in the nib file.

How to make it fit the `UITableView`?

Comment: You're not using Autolayout?

Comment: you should calculate   subview "UITableViewHeaderFooterView" dynamically.

you can post code fragment.

Comment: I use autolayout, but how am I supposed to set appropriate layout constraints on an isolated Nib? Or can you actually set autolayout constraints to a "nonexistent" yet superview in a Nib file in IB? Or do you have to do it programmaticaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, if anyone ever has the same problem:

I've read on some older stackoverflow posts that you can use a `UITableViewCell` with a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class in the header nib file. Don't do it, just use an `UIView` and it will scale the width correctly.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your question? I'm having that problem but I can't understand it completely. In my case the problem remains although I use UIView or UITableViewHeaderFooterView as the parent of my class.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you have the headerview in XIB. set autolayout constraints, leading, trailing and height properties
Refer : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2015112&seqNum=2

Comment: I'd like to use Autolayout, but you can't set constraints to a "nonexistent" yet superview from the first view in the hierarchy in a Nib file. Unless you can do it programmaticaly in some way.

Comment: setting constraints for your isolated xib is sufficient.

Comment: How do you add constraints to a Xib?